# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Time.now issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have
**Rails 3.0.9

Activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 3.0.15

TinyTds

MSSQL 2005**

I have a problem with using Time.now.
That is what I do in console:
Could someone explain this behavior?

```
    irb(main):026:0> row = Eclaim.where(:id => 1).first
    => #<Eclaim id: 1, id_user: 1, property: "inv", app_number: nil, patent_number:
    nil, native_number: nil, title: nil, applicants: nil, receive_date: nil, change_
    date: "2012-05-08 10:20:44">

    irb(main):027:0> row[:change_date] = Time.now
    => 2012-05-08 13:37:13 +0300

    irb(main):028:0> row.save
    => true

    irb(main):029:0> row = Eclaim.where(:id => 1).first
    => #<Eclaim id: 1, id_user: 1, property: "inv", app_number: nil, patent_number:
    nil, native_number: nil, title: nil, applicants: nil, receive_date: nil, change_
    date: "2012-05-08 10:37:13">

    irb(main):047:0> Time.zone
    => (GMT+00:00) UTC
```

Why am I getting the date **2012-05-08 10:37:13** in database instead of being **2012-05-08 13:37:13 +0300**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution:
In `application.rb` you should write such settings:

```
config.time_zone = 'Riga'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not an expert in dates, but what happens if you change to utc like this

```
> row[:change_date] = Time.now.localtime

> row.save
```

I think that will give the correct result. As to why this happens(my 2 cents):

One should always store the dates in some standard(people seem to differ as to what format that is). However just be aware that when storing as utc time, you will need to display the time as local time(easily done). In your example above rails is automatically converting to utc and storing it. Hope it helps

**EDIT**

Rails i think still defaults to utc time(not sure how to change this). However from utc time in database you could call localtime.What happens if you call this

```
Eclaim.first.change_date.localtime
```

This is the only way i can think off to get the localtime from utc stored in database.

Comment: Thanks for help. But using your advice I get the same result (

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord stores dates in UTC (previously known as GMT).  It converts the dates back to the local time zone when you format the date.  After Eclaim.where(:id => 1).first, do a row.change_date.

```
irb(main):029:0> row = Eclaim.where(:id => 1).first
irb(main):029:0> row.change_date
```

Comment: There is **Tue, 08 May 2012 10:37:13 UTC +00:00** in database too. **row.change_date** gives me **Tue, 08 May 2012 10:37:13 UTC +00:00** but I need **2012-05-08 13:37:13 +0300**